# How would you understand this sentence from Karlstadt's commentary on Augustine's de Spiritu et littera?

Tags: syntax, new-latin

In his Augustinkommentar, Karlstadt attacks the opinions of many Catholic "scholastic" theologians. In this passage, he seems to attack both the Thomists and Gabriel Biel, but I lose the thread of what he's saying in the middle.

> Hoc tacere: etiam si liceret, non valeo, quod Thomisticae adorationes
> et cultus sanctorum, nisi Gabrielem Bielum docentem admiscueris et
> valde crudae, hoc dico cum supportatione, et quod Magistri nostri
> eximii, hoc est scholastici. iii. d. ix. multas struunt rixas, sine
> sacris scripturis audacter determinantes, per ista non eo inficias,
> reliquias sanctorum ipsosque sanctos esse colendos, modo si ita
> colantur ut coli velint.

The beginning seems simple enough: "Even if I were permitted, I am unable to keep silent on this point, about the fact that (because?)...

Here it starts to go off the rails.

The Thomistic adorations[1] and the cult of the saints, unless you mix in Gabriel Biel's teaching, [are?] also very crude (I say this with good justification!); also [I cannot keep silent] about the fact that [because?] our distinguished Magisters, that is, the scholastics [citation of Gabriel Biel] have heaped up many controversies, adjudicating issues apart from the holy scriptures.

Then I feel more confident again:

Through these [but what exactly does "these" refer to? the scholastic rubrics or the words he just wrote] I do not deny that the relics of the saints and the saints themselves should be venerated, provided they are venerated the way they would want to be.

I'm a bit confused as to what the conjunctions connect to. The "et" before "valde crudae" doesn't seem to coordinate with anything. At least I'm taking the "et quod" to refer back to the previous "quod".

I would greatly appreciate anyone who can help me clear this up.

[1] *adorationes* is a technical term used by Thomists to describe the proper practice of veneration, as opposed to idolatrous worship [latreia]

Comment: Seems accurate to me. The "these" seems to refer to something discussed previously.